# Claim of high order electron-electron repulsion

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, electrons

A member of staff at uni once claimed in an interdisciplinary seminar that electron-electron repulsion can be to the 11th power of the reciprocal of displacement. I have tried to find this mentioned somewhere and cannot. Have I been had?

Comment: Exactly what physical quantity did they mention?

Answer (score 0):

May be he was referring to the [Lennard-Jones potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) used in quantum chemistry.

> It is a mathematically simple model that approximates the interaction
>   between a pair of neutral atoms or molecules.

This potential is of the form
$$ V(r) = \frac{A}{r^{12}} - \frac{B}{r^6} $$

> The $r^{−12}$ term, which is the repulsive term, describes Pauli
>   repulsion at short ranges due to overlapping electron orbitals,
>   and the $r^{−6}$ term, which is the attractive long-range term,
>   describes attraction at long ranges (van der Waals force, or dispersion force).

Comment: Thank you for the info. So the radius is distance between atoms, not electrons. Still, a term with a steep gradient.